# Eclipse console timestamp plugin?

Tags: eclipse

I was wondering if anyone's aware of a plugin for eclipse which will just put a simple timestamp on each line of console output.

I've had a look around at some other questions which have answers detailing how to enable timestamps on the output through the code itself, but it'd be nice to just have a print of the current system time for each line of output for any application I decide to run without requiring code edits.

Surely it's a pretty simple feature? Am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Edited to add: I'm using Eclipse Kepler.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to have timestamp printed on the console via `System.out.println()`, right ?

Comment: I just want Eclipse to automatically have a time stamp in the console for any output. So when anything at all appears in the console, there should be a time stamp next to it stating when that happened. Not through the code itself, though, I just want it to be a blanket time stamp for anything that happens through Eclipse.

Comment: I don't know how to write Eclipse plugins, but maybe this could be done: Wrap the original `System.out` with an enhanced PrintStream, which adds the Timestamps using `System.setOut(...)` [edit: same for `System.err`]. Could somebody write a Plugin to do this? I'd like to have a copy, too.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it , you have two possibilities.

**Possibility One**

Make user of any of the logging frameworks out there. Like [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/), [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j) and [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) .

**Possibility Two**

You won't be able to achieve it via the `System.out.println()`, but you can write up a custom printer function that does the job for you. Something like

```
//Set any date format you would like here
private static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss");

//Make calls to the method with the message that you want to print
private static void customDisplay(String message){
    System.out.println("["+dateFormat.format(new Date())+"] " + message);
}
```

So now instead of making a call to `System.out.println()`, make a call to your method

```
customDisplay("Some message that will be displayed with timestamp")
```

**Edit**

As far I know, we can not configure much about the eclipse's console output except for setting up the scheme and some colour look and feel.

Comment: Hi - I was really just asking if there's a plugin which will make any thing at all (every single thing) that ever appears in the Eclipse console to have a time stamp of when it showed up in the console. Not for one specific piece of code, but for everything.

Comment: AFAIK, you cant change much about the eclipse console except for setting up the layout, colour scheme and the number of lines

Comment: I figured that was probably the case, I was hoping there was a plugin I had missed though. Thanks anyhow.

Comment: Edited the answer so that in future it can be helpful